# Jump to page spot from input type=submit

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div which is hidden until populated by clicking on an input with type submit, it also unhides the div at the same time. I'd like the input click to also jump the page to that spot on the page where the div is located. Here is what I have for the input side.

```
<input class="timeline hidden" id="time" type="submit" value="Time Line" onClick="TimeLine();" title="Display the Time Line for this net" >
<a href="#timeline"></a>
```

And here is what I have for the div side.

```
<div id="timeline" class="hidden"></div>
```

This is not working and I'm not sure what I have to do to make it work.

Comment: This is because the div is hidden. Try removing `hidden` and seeing if it works.

Comment: I updated my answer a little, to show how-to, using a function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onclick="location.href='#timeline';"` on your `input` and the page will scroll to the element with the set id.

Or, as in below sample, call it in your `timeLine()` function, and then hide the `div`.

*Note, as I assume the `input`, being of type `submit`, is not suppose to actually submit anything, I changed it to be of type `button`.*

Stack snippet

```js
function timeLine() {
  location.href = '#timeline';
  document.querySelector('#timeline').classList.add('hidden');
}
```

```css
div.marker {
  margin-top: 500px;
}

div.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input class="timeline hidden" id="time" type="button" value="Time Line" onclick="timeLine();" title="Display the Time Line for this net" >
<a href="#timeline"></a>


<div class="marker">Marker for hidden div</div>
<div id="timeline" class="">Temporay text</div>
```

Comment: this worked perfectly. The input submits the javascript/php that populates the div. So I added the location.href to the onclick event.